# OnMouseEnter on Rect, Unity3D

Tags: c#, button, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my GUI creation somewhat easier and learn about it in the same time.
I dont want to buy or use a third party plugin.

I am trying to make a button script that i can use overall, i have so far made it to this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode()]
public class SceneBTN : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUIStyle myGui;
    public int theHeight = 50;
    public int theWidth = 200;
    public float verticalPlacement = 50;
    public string buttonText = "Button Text";

    void OnGUI() {
         Rect BTNtext = new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - (theWidth / 2), Screen.height - verticalPlacement, theWidth, theHeight);
         GUI.Label(BTNtext, buttonText, myGui);
    }

    void OnMouseEnter() {
        print("test");
    }

}
```

When i try to OnMouseEnter i am expecting to get a print of test in the console but nothing shows up.

I guess i am missing something very fundamental and since i have found great help on stackoverflow i turn to you guys once again (you're great by the way).

Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is in OnGUI method place following code

```
GUI.Button (new Rect(0,0,10,10), new GUIContent("Button 1", "Button 1")); 
        string hover = GUI.tooltip;

        if(hover=="Button 1"){
            Debug.Log("Mouse is over button 1");
        }
```